# Data management in the node of a double linked list

Tags: linked-list

I am implementing a double list library. i have a data element in each node. I have a function

InitList(ListPtr) which takes in the listPtr passed and initializes the first and the last elements and sets data to 1 and 2 respectively.

Now, if i append a node, i make the data in the node to be appended as 3 and make it last

I was thinking if of a function Insert(ListPtr, node). This node would have some number say, 4 and let us say the list already has 10 nodes. I insert the node at 4th position and make the data of the remaining nodes till the last +1.

My question is,what if i have 100 nodes in the list, each time i do a insert i will be doing data management.

Is it supposed to be done at all. i.e do i not need to care about data at all? I helped me during the initial development process but now it seems like it is not necessary.

Please let me know your thoughts

//Each node

```
typedef struct Node 
{
        int data;
        node_t *next;
        node_t *prev;
}node_t;


//List always begins with first and last nodes
typedef struct List
{
    node_t *first; // Pointer to first node in List
    node_t *last;  // Pointer to last node in List

}list_t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seams a bit confusing/non-explanatory. What kind of data do you have? Why do you want to keep digits in that data. As far as I got to know is that you want to sort your data which is position sensitive. First of all I don't think that you need a double linked list. A simple linked list would that for you. You may also have an option of using dynamic arrays instead. But if you really want to implement a linked list then you should not make it complex by introducing a double linked list as they are difficult to manage.
I would be able to answer better if you tell me about the nature of your data and what do you want to implement. To me there is something definitely wrong with the logic.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. You are right, if you look at the struct node_t, i have a int data element,i was under the assumption that each node should have a unique int data. The reason i wanted to keep data is to keep track of the position. may be i do not need to care about it.Thanks